# IF in a where in access + C #

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

***How can I do an IFF inside the where, where I do the filters, in my case I want the parameters that arrive with a value of 0 do not affect my query, just ignore them***

```
string query = @"
SELECT 
    P.NombreCompleto

FROM (((((((Persona AS P 
    LEFT JOIN MarcacionTemp AS MTemp ON P.codPersona = MTemp.codPersona) 
    LEFT JOIN Horario AS Ho ON MTemp.codHorario = Ho.idHorario) 
    LEFT JOIN TipoMarcacion AS TMar ON MTemp.codTipoMarcacion = TMar.idMarcacion) 
    INNER JOIN Colegio AS C ON P.codColegio = C.codColegio) 
    INNER JOIN Entidad AS E ON P.codEntidad = E.codEntidad) 
    INNER JOIN Grado AS Gr ON P.codGrado = Gr.codGrado) 
    INNER JOIN Paralelo AS Pa ON P.codParalelo = Pa.codParalelo) 
    INNER JOIN Turno AS Tu ON P.codTurno = Tu.codTurno

WHERE P.codTipo = 4         
    IIF (@turno     == 0, AND P.codTurno = @turno       , )
    IIF (@grado     == 0, AND P.codGrado = @grado       , )
    IIF (@paralelo  == 0, AND P.codParalelo = @paralelo , )";


OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", dTPGrado.Value.Date);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@turno", codTurno);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grado", codGrado);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paralelo", codParalelo);

adapter.SelectCommand = command;
DataSet.Clear();
```

Comment: You don't, use the built in logical operators, E.g. `... AND (@turno = 0 OR P.codTurno = @turno) ...`

Comment: Please read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @AlexK. you are genius, but i need only person 4. ....  :( please write your solution, is very good

Comment: @AndrewMorton that's not the problem, the values work perfectly, please read the description, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use iif in where statement. But the syntax doesn't look intuitive at first. Where expects boolean clause so what you shoud do is to convert

```
IIF (@turno     == 0, AND P.codTurno = @turno       , )
```

to

```
IIF (@turno= 0, -1, @turno) = P.codTurno
```

Note that each time a parameter @turno has a value of 0 we hange it to -1 (or anything that you are sure isn't and won't be in this column in the database.

So at the end your SQL code should look something like this

```
SELECT 
P.NombreCompleto
FROM (((((((Persona AS P 
LEFT JOIN MarcacionTemp AS MTemp ON P.codPersona = MTemp.codPersona) 
LEFT JOIN Horario AS Ho ON MTemp.codHorario = Ho.idHorario) 
LEFT JOIN TipoMarcacion AS TMar ON MTemp.codTipoMarcacion = TMar.idMarcacion) 
INNER JOIN Colegio AS C ON P.codColegio = C.codColegio) 
INNER JOIN Entidad AS E ON P.codEntidad = E.codEntidad) 
INNER JOIN Grado AS Gr ON P.codGrado = Gr.codGrado) 
INNER JOIN Paralelo AS Pa ON P.codParalelo = Pa.codParalelo) 
INNER JOIN Turno AS Tu ON P.codTurno = Tu.codTurno
WHERE P.codTipo = 4       
[and/or] IIF (@turno=0, -1, @turno) = P.codTurno
[and/or] IIF (@grado=0,-1, @grado) = P.codGrado 
[and/or] IIF (@paralelo=0, -1, @paralelo) = P.codParalelo
```